# Z rotation matrix inverting object

Tags: c++, 3d, rotation, matrix, projection

I'm currently creating a 3d game where I need to rotate shapes. To do se, I created a rotation matrix for each axis, X, Y and Z. X and Y are giving me expected results, but not Z who kind of "inverts the shape". I need it to rotate like it would rotate a 2d shape.

Here is the Z matrix :

```
zRotation.matrix[0][0] = cosf(rotationAngles.z);
zRotation.matrix[1][0] = -sinf(rotationAngles.z);
zRotation.matrix[0][1] = sinf(rotationAngles.z);
zRotation.matrix[1][1] = cosf(rotationAngles.z);
zRotation.matrix[2][2] = 1;
```

Here is what it looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/W14C7.jpg

PS : The game have an isometric perspective.

EDIT : Here is how I do matrix * vector

```
vec3 operator *(vec3 operand){
    //multiply vector by matrix

    vec3 result = vec3((operand.x * matrix[0][0]) + (operand.x * matrix[1][0]) + (operand.x * matrix[2][0]) + (operand.x * matrix[3][0]), (operand.y * matrix[0][1]) + (operand.y * matrix[1][1]) + (operand.y * matrix[2][1]) + (operand.y * matrix[3][1]), (operand.z * matrix[0][2]) + (operand.z * matrix[1][2]) + (operand.z * matrix[2][2]) + (operand.z * matrix[3][2]));
    return result;
}
```

(Fourth element is always 0)

Comment: Why is the example animated? The example code should give a single fixed rotation. Are you changing the `rotationAngles.z` value?

Comment: Are you sure you are multiplying the vertices correctly?

Comment: @Jay, Yes, I increase it to see the rotation clearly.

Comment: @Bálint I edited the post to show how I multiply vertices and matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something's not quite right here. If you take the matrix and multiply it with the vector by hand, you'll get

$$\vec v(x\cdot cos(\theta)-x\cdot sin(\theta), y\cdot sin(\theta)+y\cdot cos(\theta), 0)$$

When it should be

$$\vec v(x\cdot cos(\theta)-y\cdot sin(\theta), x\cdot sin(\theta)+y\cdot cos(\theta), 0)$$

(notice the \$x\$ and \$y\$)

The problem actually lies in your vector multiplication function. When we multiply a matrix by a vector, we are basically taking the dot products of the vector and every row of the matrix. What you are doing is multiplying every element of a row by the same coordinate. So your code should be something like this instead:

```
vec3 result = vec3(operand.x * matrix[0][0] + operand.y * matrix[1][0] + operand.z * matrix[2][0], operand.x * matrix[0][1] + operand.y * matrix[1][1] + operand.z * matrix[2][1], operand.x * matrix[0][2] + operand.y * matrix[1][2] + operand.z * matrix[2][2]);
```

Comment: I was searching for that mistake for so long ! Thanks for to answering my posts !